# SCNAction.wait not working in swift playgrounds

Tags: swift, scenekit

In my code I have a sequence in which I am telling swift to wait for a sequence to complete before i move on to another function however it seems to skip this and just move on

```
let earthSequence = SCNAction.sequence([SCNAction.wait(duration: 10),rollInGroup,rollOutGroup,earthNormalRotation])
defaultEarthNode.runAction(earthSequence)

nextFunction()
```

the result is simply moving on to the next function without waiting 10 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `nextFunction()` is called immediately after you start the action, it doesn't wait for it to be completed. `runAction` has a completionHandler you can use to know when the sequence has finished.

```
defaultEarthNode.runAction(earthSequence, completionHandler: {
    nextFunction()
})
```